# I'm not sure why this program won't compile

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, prototype

Here is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define COL 3;

void copy_row(int arr1[][COL], int rows, int arr2[], int r);

void copy_row(int arr1[][COL], int rows, int arr2[], int r){
  int i;
  if(r >= rows || r < 0)
    return;

  for(i = 0; i < COL; i++){
    arr1[r][i] = &arr2[i];
  }
}

int main(void){

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this with gcc, it says "error: expected ']' before ';' token" on line 4 and line 6.

Also, refer to the for-loop, would "arr1[r][i] = arr2[i];" do the samething as "arr1[r][i] = &arr2[i];"? Which is is (more) correct?

Comment: You don't want a semicolon at the end of that `#define` line.

Comment: `#define` statements rarely, if ever, end with a semicolon.  Suggest removing that trailing semicolon then the only compiler message is: warning:  assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast for this line: `arr1[r][i] = &arr2[i];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro `COL` is expanded to `3;`, so inside your declaration and definition looks like this:

```
int arr1[][3;]
```

Remove the semi-colon from your `#define` line.

> Also, refer to the for-loop, would `arr1[r][i] = arr2[i];` do the same thing as `arr1[r][i] = &arr2[i];`?

No.  The first one is correct.  The *lvalue* `arr1[r][i]` refers to an integer.  The *rvalue* `arr2[i]` is also an integer.

If you reference it by taking `&arr2[i]` then its type becomes `int*`, and is a pointer to element `i`, and you try to assign that to an *lvalue* of type `int`.  If you try to do that, your compiler should warn you.

Comment: Good catch. This is a good example of the difference between C statements and C preprocessor instructions.